Importing csv file into sql workbench
I just started a small data cleaning project. I am facing some problems importing a table as a csv file. When I use "table data import wizard", only about 500 rows were imported, but the actual table is about 2000 rows. I am only facing this problem on my macbook air. Applying the similar procedure on my windows pc, everything works fine. Someone knows what the problem could be?
